# Possible to customize camera firmware?

Tags: reverse-engineering, decompiling, disassembly, firmware

I have a firmware update for my camera. Would it theoretically be possible to

Decompile it, comprehend it and customize it?

Comment: make sure you read the terms of use. what you are proposing could be illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory anything is possible.  In practice, you might have a hard time.  Have you tried throwing your firmware update binary at a disassembler to see if it's real instructions and not encrypted or obscured in some way?

Even if it does happen to be unencrypted instructions, you're going to need to know something about the layout of the file - there aren't many chips out there that can start executing C code right from the reset vector.  After that, turing the disassembled binary back into high-level source code is *not* an easy task.  Certainly getting something back that you can easily understand and modify will be a big project...  good luck!

Comment: Thanks, i think i have identified the processor and located a compiler/decompiler but to be honest i have no idea if a camera even works in anything like the model i am familiar with ie the firmaware file is an executable that runs on a cpu. Fo all i know different functions of the camera - display, image processing, etc could be implemented on different architectures.

Comment: @fakeAccount22, yes - that's what will make your problem hard to solve.